# Error installing Virtualbox 5.1.10 on macOS Sierra, "The installation failed"

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, macos-sierra

I just got one of those new, shiny MacBook Pros and I'm setting up my dev environment. I downloaded Virtualbox 5.1.10 from the website and installed it and got an error "The installation failed."

Looking at the logs:

```
Nov 28 10:41:51 Zacks-MBP installd[312]: PackageKit: Install Failed: Error Domain=PKInstallErrorDomain Code=112 "An error occurred while running scripts from the package “VirtualBox.pkg”." UserInfo={NSFilePath=./postflight, NSURL=file://localhost/Volumes/VirtualBox/VirtualBox.pkg#VBoxKEXTs.pkg, PKInstallPackageIdentifier=org.virtualbox.pkg.vboxkexts, NSLocalizedDescription=An error occurred while running scripts from the package “VirtualBox.pkg”.} {
        NSFilePath = "./postflight";
        NSLocalizedDescription = "An error occurred while running scripts from the package \U201cVirtualBox.pkg\U201d.";
        NSURL = "file://localhost/Volumes/VirtualBox/VirtualBox.pkg#VBoxKEXTs.pkg";
        PKInstallPackageIdentifier = "org.virtualbox.pkg.vboxkexts";
    }
Nov 28 10:41:51 Zacks-MBP installd[312]: PackageKit: Running idle tasks
Nov 28 10:41:51 Zacks-MBP installd[312]: PackageKit: Done with sandbox removals
Nov 28 10:41:52 Zacks-MBP Installer[87983]: install:didFailWithError:Error Domain=PKInstallErrorDomain Code=112 "An error occurred while running scripts from the package “VirtualBox.pkg”." UserInfo={NSFilePath=./postflight, NSURL=file://localhost/Volumes/VirtualBox/VirtualBox.pkg#VBoxKEXTs.pkg, PKInstallPackageIdentifier=org.virtualbox.pkg.vboxkexts, NSLocalizedDescription=An error occurred while running scripts from the package “VirtualBox.pkg”.}
Nov 28 10:41:52 Zacks-MBP installd[312]: PackageKit: Removing client PKInstallDaemonClient pid=87983, uid=501 (/System/Library/CoreServices/Installer.app/Contents/MacOS/Installer)
Nov 28 10:41:52 Zacks-MBP Installer[87983]: Install failed: The Installer encountered an error that caused the installation to fail. Contact the software manufacturer for assistance.
Nov 28 10:41:52 Zacks-MBP Installer[87983]: IFDInstallController 1EF50 state = 8
Nov 28 10:41:52 Zacks-MBP Installer[87983]: Displaying 'Install Failed' UI.
Nov 28 10:41:52 Zacks-MBP Installer[87983]: 'Install Failed' UI displayed message:'The Installer encountered an error that caused the installation to fail. Contact the software manufacturer for assistance.'.
```

Information on the Virtualbox servers is pretty sparse. I tried installing via `brew` but got an error as well.

Does anyone have tricks they can share about successfully installing Virtualbox on Sierra?

Comment: Just installed Version 5.1.10 r112026 (Qt5.6.2) on macos sierra 10.12.1, no issue - anything more from log console ?

Comment: I'm also trying to install that version on 10.12.1. Barely installed anything on this machine so I doubt it's conflicting with anything. This is the full error log - http://pastebin.com/5KHMwEfJ

Comment: I'd do : 1. run the uninstall too for virtualbox; 2. reboot - if it does not work 3. check if you have a mach_kernel file at your root, if so remove

Comment: Thanks Frederic. How do I check if I have the `match_kernel` file?

Comment: https://support.apple.com/HT203829

Comment: Why would I remove that file at my root? `This file is installed with OS X and should not be deleted.` per apple

Comment: no it says so because it was for mountain lion but its not needed anymore, on a new sierra install its not there you can safely remove if you have the file

Comment: make a backup in case you worry

Comment: I'm also interested in a soution without disabling SIP or Gatekeeper. I can install Wireshark and Little Snitch without doing this, and even VMWare Fusion. Why does VirtualBox require these hoops? I'm trying to install VBox 5.4.

Answer (score 0):

After the failed installation attempt of Virtualbox 5.1.10 r112026 (Qt5.6.2) on macOS Sierra 10.12.1, running the uninstall script and restarting and then downloading and reinstalling Virtualbox worked for me.

I hope this helps someone else out.